# Using sed to get an exact value from a JSON response

Tags: json, unix, curl, sed, jq

I'm getting this string data from `curl` command

```
 {"password": [["passwordreal", "2035/01/01 00:00"]], "user": "user1", "address": "kobebkokoko.net"}
```

How do I get `passwordreal` using `sed`?

For example,

```
curl xxxx | sed -n '/ *"password"' => Been working on this long hours.
```

Comment: The short answer to "How to extract JSON values from a JSON string" is "Not with `sed` — use `jq` unless you have an alternative JSON manipulator program that you prefer".  OK, so it's not very short, but it is to the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jq:

```
| jq -r '.password[]|.[0]'
```

Output:

```
passwordreal
```

---

Use a tool that can safely handle JSON. sed is not one of them.

Comment: how do I trim ""? getting `"passwordreal"`

Comment: If you want `"passwordreal"` remove `-r`.

Comment: Or `.password[][0]` for short, or maybe what is actually wanted is: `.password[0][0]`